# Units in $R[X]$, where $R=\Bbb Z/p^2q\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two prime numbers and let $R=\Bbb Z/p^2q\Bbb Z$. find units in $R[X]$. i am not getting how to do such type of problems....

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about the problem?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

All units of $R$ will definitely be there as units in $R[x]$. But the presence of **nilpotent elements** in $R=\Bbb{Z}/p^2q\Bbb{Z}$ can give more units. In fact, an element like $1+ax$, where $a$ is a nilpotent element in $R$ is a unit in $R[x]$.

*For example:*
$a=pq$ is nilpotent in $R$ (because $a^2=0$). So $1+ax$ is a unit of $R[x]$. The reason being
$$(1+pqx)(1-pqx)=1-(pqx)^2=1.$$

**General idea:** unit + nilpotent=unit.

Comment: is there any other nilpotent elements in R

Comment: is there any other nilpotent elements in R

Comment: @RaviAgarwal In this particular ring: you have $0,1,pq,kpq$ (where $k \in \{2,3,4, \ldots p-1\}$) are all nilpotent elements. Any nilpotent element (apart from $0$ and $1$) in this ring should have both $p$ and $q$ as prime divisors because you want $a^n \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2q}$ for some $n \geq 1$.

Comment: @RaviAgarwal Just to clarify, the units need not be only degree $1$ polynomials. For example $1+pqx+pqx^2$ is also a unit because $(1+pqx+pqx^2)(1-pqx-pqx^2)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to deal with $(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z)^\times$, 'always' use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. I'm assuming $p,q$ are coprime. This reduces the problem to understanding units in $(\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)^\times$ and $(\mathbb Z/q \mathbb Z)^\times$. Hence, you are after numbers that are coprime to $p$ and also to $q$.

Comment: OP is looking for units in the **polynomial ring** and not in the coefficient ring. So your answer doesn't help.

Comment: Oh yes well spotted; but actually it does help. If it isn't a unit in the coefficient ring then it certainly won't be one in the polynomial ring either.